# Metric tensor of a disk

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, galaxies

I want to find the metric tensor of a disk ( at the moment made up of non interacting dust of constant density). I use cylindrical coordinates. I believe my metric tensor would take the form below. Where we have three unknown functions, each a function of radius and $z$. I am not entirely confident C needs to be a function of both $r$ and $z$ or just $z$. likewise for B. I am a bit new to general relativity and have not constructed many metrics tensors so I apologize if this is trivial.

\begin{equation}
g_{\mu \nu}=
\begin{pmatrix}
-A(r,z) & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & B(r,z) & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & r^2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 &C(r,z)
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

In cylindrical coordinates I believe the stress energy tensor would take the form.

\begin{equation}
T_{\mu \nu}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\rho & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

My eventual goal is to solve the corresponding Einstein field equations analytically and find orbits of test particles (very crude disk galaxy model). I thought maybe I could find my Ricci tensor and then set any $z$ derivatives to zero (for orbits at $z=0$). Do you expect this to be valid or am I missing something. Again, I apologize if this is obvious.

Comment: I think you'll find that, rather than "extremely trivial", this is likely "not analytically solveable".  I'd refer you to look up the derivation of the Kerr metric, to give an example of the most famous axysymetric exact solution of Einstein's equation, and then realize that this problem has less symmetry than that one (you have to deal with the matter distributio)

Comment: In addition to the mathematical complexity, I don't see how a bunch of dust with no pressure would stay at rest. Surely it would collapse due to its own gravity.

Comment: For a disk you can use Newton if your modell is supposed to be crude anyways, see http://notizblock.yukterez.net/viewtopic.php?t=120 but the relativistic solutions you find on arxiv etc. are hard to calculate.

Comment: It appears that your matter-content is confined on a thin disc. So you may start with an ansatz that $T_{ab}=D(r,z)\delta (z-z_0)\theta (r_0-r)\delta^0_a\delta^0_b$, (disc of radius $r_0$ at $z=z_0$) where $D(r,z)$ is such that $T_{ab}$ satisfies conservation equation w.r.t. the metric you have written.  Compute $G_{ab}$, and check the conditions on metric components